Blender 4 - in Orthographic projection view shows all invisible lines - how to return as it was in version 3?
In previews Blender version the perspective and ortho views in edit mode was the same.
Now the perspective mode is as usual, but ortho view displays all visible and invisible lines - this is very inconvenient and confusing. I'm looking for a way to disable it.
The sample of all this lines:


You'll be glad to know this is not the expected behaviour, due to a version-change. It is most probably due to an insufficient / misplaced viewport Cilipping Range .. (N panel, 'View' tab, Clip Start / End).. If that doesn't turn out to be the cause, share a version of the file showing the problem on https://blend-exchange.com/
